# How to redirect all traffic to https but a specific folder?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This is what I'm using right now to redirect all traffic to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I would like to have this configuration but exclude one particular folder. The reason I'm doing this is that I have installed an add-on domain on the current hosting account and while the main domain has an SSL certificate installed, the one that I have recently added doesn't.

Adding the addon domain creates a folder inside the root folder of the primary domains and because I'm redirecting all traffic through the htaccess configuration, it also tries to access the https version of the new addon domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude a folder using a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond  %{THE_REQUEST} !/someFolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: I see pretty much the same solution with different arguments: [R,L] [L,R=301] and [L,R=301,NE]. As far I can tell, all work the same. Is there any difference?

Comment: `R` means redirect with `302` status (temporary redirect) only. `301` is permanent redirect and that should be used. `NE` is for no escaping and highly recommended when using redirect for safeguarding when URL has special characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I'll award Kev with this answer as he was first and got fewer points - Let's give Kev a chance! Thanks again

Comment: Of course, It is your right to select any answer you think is good for you however I will correct the fact that my answer was the first to appear and Kev was last one to post an answer.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, will keep that in mind. In that case I'll reward the answer to you as you've been the first one to answer. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition into it, so use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foldername
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I will Kev's as correct as he responded first.

Comment: Actually, he was last haha xD.... @Anubhava was first :P but no worries, just glad you got the answer you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you would like to redirect all traffic that hits your site to https://, except for a single folder, right?

If that's the case, this should work:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/<folder-name>/
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R,L]
```

Just replace  with the name of the folder you want to exclude.